# Do we need to call InitCommonControls/InitCommonControlsEx before drawing OS-styled controls with DrawThemeBackground?

Tags: winapi, drawing, common-controls, visual-styles, uxtheme

I am working on a legacy ActiveX control that implements custom drawing of elementary Windows controls like combo button and check box. If the Windows visual styles are available, these controls are drawn with the [DrawThemeBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground) function like this:

```
res = DrawThemeBackground(hTheme, hDC, lPartId, lStateId, rcDraw, rcDraw);
```

The ActiveX's initialization code contains calls to [InitCommonControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrols)/[InitCommonControlsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex). Do we need these calls if OS-styled combo buttons and check boxes are not created with [CreateWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) and are fully custom drawn?

Comment: `InitCommonControls` never need call. this is empty api. it sense only in reference *comctl32.dll* (in case no direct imported any other api from it or direct load). about `InitCommonControlsEx` - read [`RegisterClassNameW`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/comctl32/api/commctrl/registerclassnamew.htm) and [`InitCommonControlsEx`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/comctl32/api/commctrl/initcommoncontrolsex.htm) - so you not need call this api too

Comment: [InitCommonControlsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-initcommoncontrolsex) Ensures that the common control DLL (Comctl32.dll) is loaded, and registers specific common control classes from the DLL. If they are not used, It's unnecessary to call `InitCommonControlsEx`.